# Package does not exist error in ANT even after adding JAR files to build path in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, ant

I have to make a Java software developed in 2010 work for research purposes. I added all the required libraries to build path of the project properly in eclipse. But as soon as I run **build.xml** I get **Package does not exist error**. I am pretty new to eclipse, don't know what I am doing wrong.

This is my **project structure**

[image]

This is my **build.xml** file.

```
<project default="init" name="Create JAR for ALEVIN">
    <description>Build the ALEVIN JAR and download all dependencies.</description>
    <echo message="java.version  = ${ant.java.version}"                   />
    <echo message="java.home     = ${java.home}"     />

    <target name="download_check">
        <available file="${basedir}/lib/junit-4.10.jar"  property="junit.existing" />
    </target>

    <target name="download_junit" unless="junit.existing">
                    <get src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/KentBeck/junit/junit-4.10.jar" dest="${basedir}/lib/junit-4.10.jar" />
    </target>



    <target name="compile" depends="download_check,download_junit">
        <mkdir dir="${basedir}/bin" />
        <javac srcdir="${basedir}/src" destdir="${basedir}/bin" encoding="UTF-8" debug="on" includeantruntime="false"  target="1.7">
            <include name="**/*.java" />
            <exclude name="vnreal/algorithms/utils/LpSolver.java" />
            <exclude name="tests/**" />
            <classpath>
                <pathelement path="${basedir}/lib/*.jar" />
                <pathelement path="${basedir}/lib/JUNG2.jar" />
                <pathelement path="${basedir}/lib/junit-4.10.jar" />
            </classpath>
        </javac>
        <copy todir="${basedir}/bin" failonerror="false">
            <fileset dir="${basedir}/src" excludes="**/*.java,tests/**" />
        </copy>
    </target>

    <target name="init" depends="compile">
        <jar destfile="${basedir}/ALEVIN.jar" filesetmanifest="mergewithoutmain" update="true">
            <manifest>
                <attribute name="Main-Class" value="vnreal.Main" />
                <attribute name="Class-Path" value=". lib/JUNG2.jar lib/junit-4.10.jar" />
            </manifest>
            <fileset dir="${basedir}/bin" />
            <filelist id="docfiles" dir="${basedir}" files="AUTHORS,CHANGELOG,COPYING,README" />
        </jar>
        <zip destfile="${basedir}/ALEVIN-src.zip" update="true">
            <zipfileset dir="${basedir}/src" prefix="src/" />
            <filelist id="docfiles" dir="${basedir}" files="AUTHORS,build.xml,CHANGELOG,COPYING,README" />
        </zip>
    </target>
</project>
```

This is my **error log**

```css
Buildfile: C:\Users\creddy\OneDrive - Ciena Corporation\Desktop\VNR\alevin-src_v2.1\alevin-2.1\build.xml
     [echo] java.version  = 1.7
     [echo] java.home     = C:\Program Files\Java\jre7
download_check:
download_junit:
compile:
    [javac] Compiling 363 source files to C:\Users\creddy\OneDrive - Ciena Corporation\Desktop\VNR\alevin-src_v2.1\alevin-2.1\bin
    [javac] C:\Users\creddy\OneDrive - Ciena Corporation\Desktop\VNR\alevin-src_v2.1\alevin-2.1\src\GLPKTest.java:1: error: package org.gnu.glpk does not exist
    [javac] import org.gnu.glpk.GLPK;
    [javac]                    ^
    [javac] C:\Users\creddy\OneDrive - Ciena Corporation\Desktop\VNR\alevin-src_v2.1\alevin-2.1\src\mulavito\algorithms\shortestpath\ShortestPathAlgorithm.java:33: error: package org.apache.commons.collections15 does not exist
    [javac] import org.apache.commons.collections15.Transformer;
    [javac]                                        ^
    [javac] C:\Users\creddy\OneDrive - Ciena Corporation\Desktop\VNR\alevin-src_v2.1\alevin-2.1\src\mulavito\algorithms\shortestpath\ShortestPathAlgorithm.java:35: error: package edu.uci.ics.jung.algorithms.shortestpath does not exist
    [javac] import edu.uci.ics.jung.algorithms.shortestpath.DijkstraShortestPath;
    [javac]                                                ^
    [javac] C:\Users\creddy\OneDrive - Ciena Corporation\Desktop\VNR\alevin-src_v2.1\alevin-2.1\src\mulavito\algorithms\shortestpath\ShortestPathAlgorithm.java:36: error: package edu.uci.ics.jung.algorithms.shortestpath does not exist
    [javac] import edu.uci.ics.jung.algorithms.shortestpath.ShortestPath;
    [javac]                                                ^
    [javac] C:\Users\creddy\OneDrive - Ciena Corporation\Desktop\VNR\alevin-src_v2.1\alevin-2.1\src\mulavito\algorithms\shortestpath\ShortestPathAlgorithm.java:37: error: package edu.uci.ics.jung.graph does not exist
    [javac] import edu.uci.ics.jung.graph.Graph;
    [javac]                              ^
    [javac] C:\Users\creddy\OneDrive - Ciena Corporation\Desktop\VNR\alevin-src_v2.1\alevin-2.1\src\mulavito\algorithms\shortestpath\ShortestPathAlgorithm.java:51: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac] public abstract class ShortestPathAlgorithm<V, E> implements ShortestPath<V, E> {
    [javac]                                                              ^
    [javac]   symbol: class ShortestPath
    [javac] C:\Users\creddy\OneDrive - Ciena Corporation\Desktop\VNR\alevin-src_v2.1\alevin-2.1\src\mulavito\algorithms\shortestpath\ShortestPathAlgorithm.java:52: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     protected final Graph<V, E> graph;
    [javac]                     ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class Graph
    [javac]   location: class ShortestPathAlgorithm<V,E>
    [javac]   where V,E are type-variables:
    [javac]     V extends Object declared in class ShortestPathAlgorithm
    [javac]     E extends Object declared in class ShortestPathAlgorithm
    [javac] C:\Users\creddy\OneDrive - Ciena Corporation\Desktop\VNR\alevin-src_v2.1\alevin-2.1\src\mulavito\algorithms\shortestpath\ShortestPathAlgorithm.java:53: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     protected final DijkstraShortestPath<V, E> dijkstra;
    [javac]                     ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class DijkstraShortestPath
    [javac]   location: class ShortestPathAlgorithm<V,E>
    [javac]   where V,E are type-variables:
    [javac]     V extends Object declared in class ShortestPathAlgorithm
    [javac]     E extends Object declared in class ShortestPathAlgorithm
    [javac] C:\Users\creddy\OneDrive - Ciena Corporation\Desktop\VNR\alevin-src_v2.1\alevin-2.1\src\mulavito\algorithms\shortestpath\ShortestPathAlgorithm.java:54: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     protected final Transformer<E, Number> nev;
    [javac]                     ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class Transformer
    [javac]   location: class ShortestPathAlgorithm<V,E>
    [javac]   where V,E are type-variables:
    [javac]     V extends Object declared in class ShortestPathAlgorithm
    [javac]     E extends Object declared in class ShortestPathAlgorithm
    [javac] C:\Users\creddy\OneDrive - Ciena Corporation\Desktop\VNR\alevin-src_v2.1\alevin-2.1\src\mulavito\algorithms\shortestpath\ShortestPathAlgorithm.java:56: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     protected ShortestPathAlgorithm(Graph<V, E> graph,
    [javac]                                     ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class Graph
    [javac]   location: class ShortestPathAlgorithm<V,E>
    [javac]   where V,E are type-variables:
    [javac]     V extends Object declared in class ShortestPathAlgorithm
    [javac]     E extends Object declared in class ShortestPathAlgorithm
    [javac] C:\Users\creddy\OneDrive - Ciena Corporation\Desktop\VNR\alevin-src_v2.1\alevin-2.1\src\mulavito\algorithms\shortestpath\ShortestPathAlgorithm.java:57: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]             Transformer<E, Number> nev) {
    [javac]             ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class Transformer
    [javac]   location: class ShortestPathAlgorithm<V,E>
    [javac]   where V,E are type-variables:
    [javac]     V extends Object declared in class ShortestPathAlgorithm
    [javac]     E extends Object declared in class ShortestPathAlgorithm
    [javac] C:\Users\creddy\OneDrive - Ciena Corporation\Desktop\VNR\alevin-src_v2.1\alevin-2.1\src\mulavito\algorithms\shortestpath\disjoint\SuurballeTarjan.java:40: error: package org.apache.commons.collections15 does not exist
    [javac] import org.apache.commons.collections15.ListUtils;
    [javac]                                        ^
    [javac] C:\Users\creddy\OneDrive - Ciena Corporation\Desktop\VNR\alevin-src_v2.1\alevin-2.1\src\mulavito\algorithms\shortestpath\disjoint\SuurballeTarjan.java:41: error: package org.apache.commons.collections15 does not exist
    [javac] import org.apache.commons.collections15.Transformer;
    [javac]                                        ^
    [javac] C:\Users\creddy\OneDrive - Ciena Corporation\Desktop\VNR\alevin-src_v2.1\alevin-2.1\src\mulavito\algorithms\shortestpath\disjoint\SuurballeTarjan.java:42: error: package org.apache.commons.collections15.functors does not exist
    [javac] import org.apache.commons.collections15.functors.MapTransformer;
    [javac]                                                 ^
    [javac] C:\Users\creddy\OneDrive - Ciena Corporation\Desktop\VNR\alevin-src_v2.1\alevin-2.1\src\mulavito\algorithms\shortestpath\disjoint\SuurballeTarjan.java:44: error: package edu.uci.ics.jung.algorithms.shortestpath does not exist
    [javac] import edu.uci.ics.jung.algorithms.shortestpath.DijkstraShortestPath;
    [javac]                                                ^
    [javac] C:\Users\creddy\OneDrive - Ciena Corporation\Desktop\VNR\alevin-src_v2.1\alevin-2.1\src\mulavito\algorithms\shortestpath\disjoint\SuurballeTarjan.java:45: error: package edu.uci.ics.jung.graph does not exist
    [javac] import edu.uci.ics.jung.graph.DirectedOrderedSparseMultigraph;
    [javac]                              ^
    [javac] C:\Users\creddy\OneDrive - Ciena Corporation\Desktop\VNR\alevin-src_v2.1\alevin-2.1\src\mulavito\algorithms\shortestpath\disjoint\SuurballeTarjan.java:46: error: package edu.uci.ics.jung.graph does not exist
    [javac] import edu.uci.ics.jung.graph.Graph;
    [javac]                              ^
    [javac] C:\Users\creddy\OneDrive - Ciena Corporation\Desktop\VNR\alevin-src_v2.1\alevin-2.1\src\mulavito\algorithms\shortestpath\disjoint\SuurballeTarjan.java:47: error: package edu.uci.ics.jung.graph.util does not exist
    [javac] import edu.uci.ics.jung.graph.util.EdgeType;
    [javac]                                   ^
    [javac] C:\Users\creddy\OneDrive - Ciena Corporation\Desktop\VNR\alevin-src_v2.1\alevin-2.1\src\mulavito\algorithms\shortestpath\disjoint\SuurballeTarjan.java:85: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     public SuurballeTarjan(Graph<V, E> graph, Transformer<E, Number> nev) {
    [javac]                            ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class Graph
    [javac]   location: class SuurballeTarjan<V,E>
    [javac]   where V,E are type-variables:
    [javac]     V extends Object declared in class SuurballeTarjan
    [javac]     E extends Object declared in class SuurballeTarjan
    [javac] C:\Users\creddy\OneDrive - Ciena Corporation\Desktop\VNR\alevin-src_v2.1\alevin-2.1\src\mulavito\algorithms\shortestpath\disjoint\SuurballeTarjan.java:85: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     public SuurballeTarjan(Graph<V, E> graph, Transformer<E, Number> nev) {
    [javac]                                               ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class Transformer
    [javac]   location: class SuurballeTarjan<V,E>
    [javac]   where V,E are type-variables:
    [javac]     V extends Object declared in class SuurballeTarjan
    [javac]     E extends Object declared in class SuurballeTarjan
    [javac] C:\Users\creddy\OneDrive - Ciena Corporation\Desktop\VNR\alevin-src_v2.1\alevin-2.1\src\mulavito\algorithms\shortestpath\disjoint\SuurballeTarjan.java:104: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     public SuurballeTarjan(Graph<V, E> graph, Transformer<E, Number> nev,
    [javac]                            ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class Graph
    [javac]   location: class SuurballeTarjan<V,E>
    [javac]   where V,E are type-variables:
    [javac]     V extends Object declared in class SuurballeTarjan
    [javac]     E extends Object declared in class SuurballeTarjan
    [javac] C:\Users\creddy\OneDrive - Ciena Corporation\Desktop\VNR\alevin-src_v2.1\alevin-2.1\src\mulavito\algorithms\shortestpath\disjoint\SuurballeTarjan.java:104: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     public SuurballeTarjan(Graph<V, E> graph, Transformer<E, Number> nev,
    [javac]                                               ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class Transformer
    [javac]   location: class SuurballeTarjan<V,E>
    [javac]   where V,E are type-variables:
    [javac]     V extends Object declared in class SuurballeTarjan
    [javac]     E extends Object declared in class SuurballeTarjan
    [javac] C:\Users\creddy\OneDrive - Ciena Corporation\Desktop\VNR\alevin-src_v2.1\alevin-2.1\src\mulavito\algorithms\shortestpath\disjoint\SuurballeTarjan.java:171: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     private void validate(V source, V target, List<E> path, Graph<V, E> graph)
    [javac]                                                             ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class Graph
    [javac]   location: class SuurballeTarjan<V,E>
    [javac]   where V,E are type-variables:
    [javac]     V extends Object declared in class SuurballeTarjan
    [javac]     E extends Object declared in class SuurballeTarjan
    [javac] C:\Users\creddy\OneDrive - Ciena Corporation\Desktop\VNR\alevin-src_v2.1\alevin-2.1\src\mulavito\algorithms\shortestpath\disjoint\SuurballeTarjan.java:290: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     private Graph<V, E> reverseEdges(Graph<V, E> graph, List<E> path) {
    [javac]                                      ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class Graph
    [javac]   location: class SuurballeTarjan<V,E>
    [javac]   where V,E are type-variables:
    [javac]     V extends Object declared in class SuurballeTarjan
    [javac]     E extends Object declared in class SuurballeTarjan
    [javac] C:\Users\creddy\OneDrive - Ciena Corporation\Desktop\VNR\alevin-src_v2.1\alevin-2.1\src\mulavito\algorithms\shortestpath\disjoint\SuurballeTarjan.java:290: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     private Graph<V, E> reverseEdges(Graph<V, E> graph, List<E> path) {
    [javac]             ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class Graph
    [javac]   location: class SuurballeTarjan<V,E>
    [javac]   where V,E are type-variables:
    [javac]     V extends Object declared in class SuurballeTarjan
    [javac]     E extends Object declared in class SuurballeTarjan
    [javac] C:\Users\creddy\OneDrive - Ciena Corporation\Desktop\VNR\alevin-src_v2.1\alevin-2.1\src\mulavito\algorithms\shortestpath\disjoint\SuurballeTarjan.java:322: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     private Transformer<E, Double> lengthTransformation(Graph<V, E> graph1,
    [javac]                                                         ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class Graph
    [javac]   location: class SuurballeTarjan<V,E>
    [javac]   where V,E are type-variables:
    [javac]     V extends Object declared in class SuurballeTarjan
    [javac]     E extends Object declared in class SuurballeTarjan
    [javac] C:\Users\creddy\OneDrive - Ciena Corporation\Desktop\VNR\alevin-src_v2.1\alevin-2.1\src\mulavito\algorithms\shortestpath\disjoint\SuurballeTarjan.java:323: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]             Transformer<V, Number> slTrans) {
    [javac]             ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class Transformer
    [javac]   location: class SuurballeTarjan<V,E>
    [javac]   where V,E are type-variables:
    [javac]     V extends Object declared in class SuurballeTarjan
    [javac]     E extends Object declared in class SuurballeTarjan
    [javac] C:\Users\creddy\OneDrive - Ciena Corporation\Desktop\VNR\alevin-src_v2.1\alevin-2.1\src\mulavito\algorithms\shortestpath\disjoint\SuurballeTarjan.java:322: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     private Transformer<E, Double> lengthTransformation(Graph<V, E> graph1,
    [javac]             ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class Transformer
    [javac]   location: class SuurballeTarjan<V,E>
    [javac]   where V,E are type-variables:
    [javac]     V extends Object declared in class SuurballeTarjan
    [javac]     E extends Object declared in class SuurballeTarjan
    [javac] C:\Users\creddy\OneDrive - Ciena Corporation\Desktop\VNR\alevin-src_v2.1\alevin-2.1\src\mulavito\algorithms\shortestpath\ksp\Eppstein.java:39: error: package org.apache.commons.collections15 does not exist
    [javac] import org.apache.commons.collections15.Transformer;
    [javac]                                        ^
    [javac] C:\Users\creddy\OneDrive - Ciena Corporation\Desktop\VNR\alevin-src_v2.1\alevin-2.1\src\mulavito\algorithms\shortestpath\ksp\Eppstein.java:40: error: package org.apache.commons.collections15.functors does not exist
    [javac] import org.apache.commons.collections15.functors.MapTransformer;
    [javac]                                                 ^
    [javac] C:\Users\creddy\OneDrive - Ciena Corporation\Desktop\VNR\alevin-src_v2.1\alevin-2.1\src\mulavito\algorithms\shortestpath\ksp\Eppstein.java:42: error: package edu.uci.ics.jung.graph does not exist
    [javac] import edu.uci.ics.jung.graph.Graph;
    [javac]                              ^
    [javac] C:\Users\creddy\OneDrive - Ciena Corporation\Desktop\VNR\alevin-src_v2.1\alevin-2.1\src\mulavito\algorithms\shortestpath\ksp\KShortestPathAlgorithm.java:36: error: package org.apache.commons.collections15 does not exist
    [javac] import org.apache.commons.collections15.Transformer;
    [javac]                                        ^
    [javac] C:\Users\creddy\OneDrive - Ciena Corporation\Desktop\VNR\alevin-src_v2.1\alevin-2.1\src\mulavito\algorithms\shortestpath\ksp\KShortestPathAlgorithm.java:38: error: package edu.uci.ics.jung.graph does not exist
    [javac] import edu.uci.ics.jung.graph.Graph;
    [javac]                              ^
    [javac] C:\Users\creddy\OneDrive - Ciena Corporation\Desktop\VNR\alevin-src_v2.1\alevin-2.1\src\mulavito\algorithms\shortestpath\ksp\Eppstein.java:103: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     public Eppstein(Graph<V, E> graph, Transformer<E, Number> nev) {
    [javac]                     ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class Graph
    [javac]   location: class Eppstein<V,E>
    [javac]   where V,E are type-variables:
    [javac]     V extends Object declared in class Eppstein
    [javac]     E extends Object declared in class Eppstein
    [javac] C:\Users\creddy\OneDrive - Ciena Corporation\Desktop\VNR\alevin-src_v2.1\alevin-2.1\src\mulavito\algorithms\shortestpath\ksp\Eppstein.java:103: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     public Eppstein(Graph<V, E> graph, Transformer<E, Number> nev) {
    [javac]                                        ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class Transformer
    [javac]   location: class Eppstein<V,E>
    [javac]   where V,E are type-variables:
    [javac]     V extends Object declared in class Eppstein
    [javac]     E extends Object declared in class Eppstein
    [javac] C:\Users\creddy\OneDrive - Ciena Corporation\Desktop\VNR\alevin-src_v2.1\alevin-2.1\src\mulavito\algorithms\shortestpath\ksp\Eppstein.java:178: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     private Transformer<E, Double> prepareTransformations(V target) {
    [javac]             ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class Transformer
    [javac]   location: class Eppstein<V,E>
    [javac]   where V,E are type-variables:
    [javac]     V extends Object declared in class Eppstein
    [javac]     E extends Object declared in class Eppstein
    [javac] C:\Users\creddy\OneDrive - Ciena Corporation\Desktop\VNR\alevin-src_v2.1\alevin-2.1\src\mulavito\algorithms\shortestpath\ksp\KShortestPathAlgorithm.java:51: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     protected KShortestPathAlgorithm(Graph<V, E> graph,
    [javac]                                      ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class Graph
    [javac]   location: class KShortestPathAlgorithm<V,E>
    [javac]   where V,E are type-variables:
    [javac]     V extends Object declared in class KShortestPathAlgorithm
    [javac]     E extends Object declared in class KShortestPathAlgorithm
    [javac] C:\Users\creddy\OneDrive - Ciena Corporation\Desktop\VNR\alevin-src_v2.1\alevin-2.1\src\mulavito\algorithms\shortestpath\ksp\KShortestPathAlgorithm.java:52: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]             Transformer<E, Number> nev) {
    [javac]             ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class Transformer
    [javac]   location: class KShortestPathAlgorithm<V,E>
    [javac]   where V,E are type-variables:
    [javac]     V extends Object declared in class KShortestPathAlgorithm
    [javac]     E extends Object declared in class KShortestPathAlgorithm
    [javac] C:\Users\creddy\OneDrive - Ciena Corporation\Desktop\VNR\alevin-src_v2.1\alevin-2.1\src\mulavito\algorithms\shortestpath\ksp\Yen.java:38: error: package org.apache.commons.collections15 does not exist
    [javac] import org.apache.commons.collections15.ListUtils;
    [javac]                                        ^
    [javac] C:\Users\creddy\OneDrive - Ciena Corporation\Desktop\VNR\alevin-src_v2.1\alevin-2.1\src\mulavito\algorithms\shortestpath\ksp\Yen.java:39: error: package org.apache.commons.collections15 does not exist
    [javac] import org.apache.commons.collections15.Predicate;
    [javac]                                        ^
    [javac] C:\Users\creddy\OneDrive - Ciena Corporation\Desktop\VNR\alevin-src_v2.1\alevin-2.1\src\mulavito\algorithms\shortestpath\ksp\Yen.java:40: error: package org.apache.commons.collections15 does not exist
    [javac] import org.apache.commons.collections15.Transformer;
    [javac]                                        ^
    [javac] C:\Users\creddy\OneDrive - Ciena Corporation\Desktop\VNR\alevin-src_v2.1\alevin-2.1\src\mulavito\algorithms\shortestpath\ksp\Yen.java:42: error: package edu.uci.ics.jung.algorithms.filters does not exist
    [javac] import edu.uci.ics.jung.algorithms.filters.EdgePredicateFilter;
    [javac]                                           ^
    [javac] C:\Users\creddy\OneDrive - Ciena Corporation\Desktop\VNR\alevin-src_v2.1\alevin-2.1\src\mulavito\algorithms\shortestpath\ksp\Yen.java:43: error: package edu.uci.ics.jung.algorithms.shortestpath does not exist
    [javac] import edu.uci.ics.jung.algorithms.shortestpath.DijkstraShortestPath;
    [javac]                                                ^
    [javac] C:\Users\creddy\OneDrive - Ciena Corporation\Desktop\VNR\alevin-src_v2.1\alevin-2.1\src\mulavito\algorithms\shortestpath\ksp\Yen.java:44: error: package edu.uci.ics.jung.graph does not exist
    [javac] import edu.uci.ics.jung.graph.Graph;
    [javac]                              ^
    [javac] C:\Users\creddy\OneDrive - Ciena Corporation\Desktop\VNR\alevin-src_v2.1\alevin-2.1\src\mulavito\algorithms\shortestpath\ksp\Yen.java:97: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     public Yen(Graph<V, E> graph, Transformer<E, Number> nev) {
    [javac]                ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class Graph
    [javac]   location: class Yen<V,E>
    [javac]   where V,E are type-variables:
    [javac]     V extends Object declared in class Yen
    [javac]     E extends Object declared in class Yen
    [javac] C:\Users\creddy\OneDrive - Ciena Corporation\Desktop\VNR\alevin-src_v2.1\alevin-2.1\src\mulavito\algorithms\shortestpath\ksp\Yen.java:97: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     public Yen(Graph<V, E> graph, Transformer<E, Number> nev) {
    [javac]                                   ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class Transformer
    [javac]   location: class Yen<V,E>
    [javac]   where V,E are type-variables:
    [javac]     V extends Object declared in class Yen
    [javac]     E extends Object declared in class Yen
    [javac] C:\Users\creddy\OneDrive - Ciena Corporation\Desktop\VNR\alevin-src_v2.1\alevin-2.1\src\mulavito\algorithms\shortestpath\ksp\Yen.java:217: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     private Graph<V, E> blockFilter(List<E> head, V deviation,
    [javac]             ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class Graph
    [javac]   location: class Yen<V,E>
    [javac]   where V,E are type-variables:
    [javac]     V extends Object declared in class Yen
    [javac]     E extends Object declared in class Yen
    [javac] C:\Users\creddy\OneDrive - Ciena Corporation\Desktop\VNR\alevin-src_v2.1\alevin-2.1\src\mulavito\graph\AbstractLayerStack.java:37: error: package org.apache.commons.collections15.iterators does not exist
    [javac] import org.apache.commons.collections15.iterators.UnmodifiableIterator;
    [javac]                                                  ^
    [javac] C:\Users\creddy\OneDrive - Ciena Corporation\Desktop\VNR\alevin-src_v2.1\alevin-2.1\src\mulavito\graph\ILayer.java:31: error: package org.apache.commons.collections15 does not exist
    [javac] import org.apache.commons.collections15.Factory;
    [javac]                                        ^
    [javac] C:\Users\creddy\OneDrive - Ciena Corporation\Desktop\VNR\alevin-src_v2.1\alevin-2.1\src\mulavito\graph\ILayer.java:33: error: package edu.uci.ics.jung.graph does not exist
    [javac] import edu.uci.ics.jung.graph.Graph;
    [javac]                              ^
    [javac] C:\Users\creddy\OneDrive - Ciena Corporation\Desktop\VNR\alevin-src_v2.1\alevin-2.1\src\mulavito\graph\ILayer.java:35: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac] public interface ILayer<V extends IVertex, E extends IEdge> extends Graph<V, E> {
    [javac]                                                                     ^
    [javac]   symbol: class Graph
    [javac] C:\Users\creddy\OneDrive - Ciena Corporation\Desktop\VNR\alevin-src_v2.1\alevin-2.1\src\mulavito\graph\ILayer.java:40: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     public Factory<E> getEdgeFactory();
    [javac]            ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class Factory
    [javac]   location: interface ILayer<V,E>
    [javac]   where V,E are type-variables:
    [javac]     V extends IVertex declared in interface ILayer
    [javac]     E extends IEdge declared in interface ILayer
    [javac] C:\Users\creddy\OneDrive - Ciena Corporation\Desktop\VNR\alevin-src_v2.1\alevin-2.1\src\mulavito\graph\generators\ReachabilityEnsuringEdgeGeneratorWrapper.java:38: error: package edu.uci.ics.jung.algorithms.shortestpath does not exist
    [javac] import edu.uci.ics.jung.algorithms.shortestpath.DijkstraShortestPath;
    [javac]                                                ^
    [javac] C:\Users\creddy\OneDrive - Ciena Corporation\Desktop\VNR\alevin-src_v2.1\alevin-2.1\src\mulavito\graph\generators\ReachabilityEnsuringEdgeGeneratorWrapper.java:39: error: package edu.uci.ics.jung.graph.util does not exist
    [javac] import edu.uci.ics.jung.graph.util.Pair;
    [javac]                                   ^
    [javac] C:\Users\creddy\OneDrive - Ciena Corporation\Desktop\VNR\alevin-src_v2.1\alevin-2.1\src\mulavito\graph\transformers\IEdgeWeightTransformer.java:31: error: package org.apache.commons.collections15 does not exist
    [javac] import org.apache.commons.collections15.Transformer;
    [javac]                                        ^
    [javac] C:\Users\creddy\OneDrive - Ciena Corporation\Desktop\VNR\alevin-src_v2.1\alevin-2.1\src\mulavito\graph\transformers\IEdgeWeightTransformer.java:50: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac] public interface IEdgeWeightTransformer<E> extends Transformer<E, Number> {
    [javac]                                                    ^
    [javac]   symbol: class Transformer
    [javac] C:\Users\creddy\OneDrive - Ciena Corporation\Desktop\VNR\alevin-src_v2.1\alevin-2.1\src\mulavito\gui\components\GraphPanel.java:54: error: package org.apache.commons.collections15.list does not exist
    [javac] import org.apache.commons.collections15.list.UnmodifiableList;
    [javac]                                             ^
    [javac] C:\Users\creddy\OneDrive - Ciena Corporation\Desktop\VNR\alevin-src_v2.1\alevin-
```

Comment: Are you sure that `pathelement` accepts wildcards like that? And what does the Eclipse Java Build Path have to do with the contents of this Ant file, anyway?

Comment: Okay I added that line to just test if it works or not. As I said I am pretty new to eclipse. If there are missing jar files, the first solution is to add the files to build path right?

Comment: Ant and Eclipse are not automatically kept in sync. Your problem happens when using Ant. You would address it using Ant.